# Phonegap barcode scanner portrait mode

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, barcode-scanner

I'm doing some testing on QR code reader with phonegap plugin
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner

I installed the code in to index.js

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
  function (result) {
      alert("We got a barcode not \n" +
            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
            "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
  }, 
  function (error) {
      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
  },
  {
      "preferFrontCamera" : true, // iOS and Android
      "showFlipCameraButton" : true, // iOS and Android
      "prompt" : "Place a barcode inside the scan area", // supported on Android only
      "formats" : "QR_CODE,PDF_417", // default: all but PDF_417 and RSS_EXPANDED
      "orientation" : "portrait" // Android only (portrait|landscape), default unset so it rotates with the device
  }
);
```

everything seems working except for this section, does not seem to trigger at all.
I need the scanner to be portrait but it's always in landscape mode.

```
{
      "preferFrontCamera" : true, // iOS and Android
      "showFlipCameraButton" : true, // iOS and Android
      "prompt" : "Place a barcode inside the scan area", // supported on Android only
      "formats" : "QR_CODE,PDF_417", // default: all but PDF_417 and RSS_EXPANDED
      "orientation" : "portrait" // Android only (portrait|landscape), default unset so it rotates with the device
  }
```

I build the app on a Adobe phonegap build, and installed on Android 6.0.1
Is there anything I missed or done something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

My bad
I didn't updated config.xml.
apparently phonegap build was using old version of plugin.

needed this lines

```
<plugin spec="https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner#6.0.1" />
<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
```